# Identifying Train/carriage/seats on Austrian Rail

Tags: trains

This might sound like a really daft/pointless question, but my tickets say, if Google translate is correct that my train to Budapest from Vienna (Wein HBF) is train 49, with a window seat by a table then 076, is this a seat number?  will there be a ticket with my name on it on the seat like they do on reserved seats in the UK?

Also, I'm on the sleeper from Vienna to Venice, I assume from the ticket, train 237 berth 403, are the sleeper berths labeled from the outside of the carriage so are easy to find?

Sorry for the basic questions, just like to know stuff beforehand.

Comment: user13190 has already answered your question, but if you'd like some more information about your night train journey, [this Seat61 page](https://www.seat61.com/trains-and-routes/nightjet.htm) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, 076 is a seat number. I would look around for a carriage number on your ticket too. There will not be a ticket on the seat.

403 is the sleeper carriage number (actually it's a "couchette"). It's labelled on the outside, and there will be several staff around to help when you board. Your ticket should also indicate your berth number(s) (Liegeplätze), probably formatted with a leading zero and perhaps under "Oben", "Mitte" or "Unten" indicating whether it is the top, middle, or bottom bunk. For example, in my compartment of carriage 403 last week the berths were 041 - 046.

Comment: thank you for your reply, all that makes perfect sense now.